# Vaadin 14.9 - Redirect on Session Destroy Event

Tags: session, vaadin

I'm struggling with session timeout on Vaadin. In particular I'm trying to redirect user to a static page on SessionDestroyEvent (triggered by server.servlet.session.timeout). Is that possible ? I've already tried with VaadinServletResponse.sendRedirect in addSessionDestroyListener method implementing VaadinServiceInitListener, but it seems there is no effect on the user side.

Many thanks for your help,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't work. Once the `SessionDestroyEvent` is fired, the session has already been destroyed. As you can see from the JavaDoc:

```
Event fired when a Vaadin service session is no longer in use.
```

What you can do instead is provide a session expired URL in customized system messages:

```java
public class CustomInitServiceListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener {
    @Override
    public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
        event.getSource().setSystemMessagesProvider(new SystemMessagesProvider() {
            @Override
            public SystemMessages getSystemMessages(SystemMessagesInfo systemMessagesInfo) {
                CustomizedSystemMessages messages = new CustomizedSystemMessages();
                messages.setSessionExpiredCaption("Session expired");
                messages.setSessionExpiredMessage("Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC key to continue.");
                messages.setSessionExpiredURL("session-expired.html");
                messages.setSessionExpiredNotificationEnabled(true);
                return messages;
            }
        });
    };
};
```

The browser will be redirected to the URL after the session expired notification is shown. If you want to redirect without showing the notification, just disable the notification. See more in the docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/customize-system-messages

Comment: To answer a couple of questions one might have: you can indeed get the custom redirect without a message in the browser by setting `messages.setSessionExpiredNotificationEnabled(false)`, and if using Spring-Vaadin integration, annotating the class with `@Component` is sufficient to get it registered.